# Display Montserrat in Bulgarian Cyrillic

Tags: html, google-fonts, webflow

I’m trying to force the browsers to display the content of my website in the Bulgarian stylistic alternative of the Montserrat font.

Here’s a comparison.

[glyph comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIlLF.png)

I’m fairly new to web development and I’m wondering how to trigger this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting a compatible font and using `lang="bg"` in an enclosing HTML tag.

(Example taken from a random tweet by the Bulgarian PM.)

```css
* {
  font-family:TwitterChirp, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div lang="ru">
За 7 месеца видяхме как 2 млрд могат да отидат за икономически мерки за всички хора, вместо за джобовете на двайсетина, а бизнеса може да работи спокойно. 
</div>
<div lang="bg">
За 7 месеца видяхме как 2 млрд могат да отидат за икономически мерки за всички хора, вместо за джобовете на двайсетина, а бизнеса може да работи спокойно. 
</div>
```